# Average kinetic energy associated with a quantum mechanical wave function is related to its spatial rate of change

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am trying the prove the statement:

> The average kinetic energy associated with a quantum mechanical wave function is related to its spatial rate of change (in the context of infinite square well)

My argument so far:

The energy eigenfunctions in a infinite square well is:  $u_n(x) = \sqrt\frac{2}{a} \sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x \right)$  for $n=1,2,3...$

As $n$ gets bigger the wiggles increases:

> [image]

The expectation value of the kinetic energy is:

> [image]

However I am struggling to show that as $n$ gets bigger the integral value gets bigger. I know it does by plugging in different values but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the eigenstates is a plane wave, and for a plane wave $\sin(k x)$, the energy is given by $k^2/2m$, which of course is related to the rate of change of $\sin(k x)$ through k. This result for plane waves applies in any context (not only the square well), and it comes directly from the fact that the momentum operator in position space is given by the gradient. Since this is basically what the statement that you have been asked to prove is asserting, I wouldn't use the position-space representation of the momentum operator to prove it (since you would be using the result you want to prove). I would prove instead that the momentum operator takes the form of the gradient in the position-basis. Proofs of this can be found in every quantum mechanics textbook.